# Same button across all view controllers in ios app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, viewcontroller

I am developing an app with 10 view controllers, including 2 webview controllers. Every view controller contains a 'send feedback' button on top right with exactly same style and functionality.
Right now, I am writing exact same code in each view controller for the buttons.
I was wondering if there is a way to write the method only at one place and use it for all the buttons, since the function is same.
I am using swift 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new subclass of view controller:

```
class SendFeedbackViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sendFeedbackButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendFeedback() {
        /* do whatever you need */
    }
}
```

Then subclass all your view controllers from this new view controller:

```
class YourViewController: SendFeedbackViewController {
    /* your entire logic */
}
```

In storyboard set class type:
[image]

Now you can connect your send feedback button outlet and action:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use extension of UIViewController.

```
extension UIViewController {
   func sendFeedBack() {
     //write your code here
   }
}
```

And call from any ViewController.

Comment: An extension is a good way to do this, however it may be better to first subclass UIViewController then put an extension on the subclass.